# Strapi on Digital Ocean app not using production configs

Tags: digital-ocean, strapi

I've installed a Strapi application using Digital Ocean's App Platform. I'm also using a managed Postgres database. I can deploy with production configurations, however, Strapi is still creating and using the default sqlite database.

I followed Strapi's deployment docs here: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/hosting-guides/digitalocean-app-platform.html#add-a-managed-database

I have set the `/config/env/production/database.js` and `/config/env/production/server.js` files. In the console log when the application is being built, it also confirms that it's being run in production mode. I'm not sure why it's ignoring the database.js file though for postgres.

Comment: hey there, have a different problem regarding the Strapi application using Digital Ocean's App Platform, even I have used a managed postgres db. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to explicitly set `NODE_ENV=production` for the container/app's environment.